# Putting arraylist in contentvalues

Tags: java, android

I'm following this tutorial on saving using sqldatabases, and on the add method its using contentvalues. I need to add an arraylist, but i'm getting an error when i try to. It's telling me to change the return type of the method i have to string because the arraylist is not applicable. This is the tutorial, http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/. I'm at the part where it's making the CRUD operations.

Comment: Can you post the specific lines of code you're referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not completely sure what you are trying to do but maybe I can head it off...

1) You can't put an ArrayList into a ContentValues.  The example converts cursors full of columns into ArrayLists of POJOs.  You could convert an ArrayList of POJOs into an array of ContentValues, and then bulkInsert that.

2) IMO..., you should try doing away with those POJOs, if you can.  Android likes cursors.  Cursors and ContentValues.  I think Rich Hickey does too.  That's good enough for me.